# JQuery date formatting function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I get a (date) value from the database that is returned in the following format: 2013-03-01. I will like to output it on my page as Friday, March 2013. Please Is there a JQuery function available for this?

Comment: There's plenty of answers to this. You could start by searching for `javascript format date` on Google or here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: in my experience, its always better to format the date in server side. Languages like Java and C# supports wide array of date formats.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a JQuery function available for this?

No, jQuery doesn't provide any date formatting abilities.

There are **lots** of libraries that do, such as [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com), which is about 6.4k. Or of course, doing it yourself is about one line of data (the names of the months) and six or seven lines of code.

Comment: +1 wow dat is one heck of a library

Answer (score 1):

THere is no method you can use with jQuery. You can use some custom js libraries such as [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/).

Using XDate you can do this as below

```
var myDateString = "2013-03-01";
myDateStringArray =  myDateString.split("-");
var d = new XDate(myDateStringArray[0], (parseInt(myDateStringArray[1])-1), myDateStringArray[2]);

var myNewDate = d.toString("dddd MMMM yyyy"); 
alert(myNewDate );
```

checkout the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zWcU5/

XDate download http://arshaw.com/xdate/